# What this part of code does: BigInteger.valueOf(counter).testBit(j)

Tags: java, biginteger

There is this code snippet I don't understand. Could you explain what it does?

```
for (int counter = 1; counter < opsize; counter++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (BigInteger.valueOf(counter).testBit(j)) {
            System.out.print(arr[j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#testBit(int)

Answer (score 0):

The `testBit(int i)` method of `BigInteger` returns a `boolean` if the bit at position i is set(true) or not(false). 
So this code checks if the jth bit is set and if it returns true then it prints the array (`arr`) element at index `j`.